# What can I do with left over money if I don't want to spend it?

Tags: death-rally-2012

Is it possible to bank left over money in Death Rally 2012 ? When I have a fully upgraded car and weapon, and I have some left over money from the race, I can't seem to get to the next menu and have to "spend" it "somewhere".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have no weapon or car upgrades with left over money, `Fame` just adds automatically to your character.

[image: Money to fame points]

Comment: I can't find any links to support the answer, but that's how it works, It seems the didn't want us to keep our earnings to buy a huge car whenever...

Comment: Make sens, I'm going to test it tonight and mark it as an answer!

Comment: actually I've just tested it and it automatically spends the money on Fame points